# Ruby - Parsing file while keeping track of connected data across multiple lines

Tags: ruby, file, hash, multidimensional-array

I am working on a script to parse out certain values from a file where configuration data is spread across multiple lines and have been having a lot of trouble doing it in Ruby.  The data is shown below.  The piece that ties data together is the Unit number.  What I need to do is grab the Unit, AdminIPAddress, InterfaceDisplayString, and Name values from  this data and save it in such a way that it makes sense.  To me, a multi-dimensional Perl hash would be perfect, but the syntax is beyond my understanding of the Ruby language.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I'd like the data to be in a hash like the following:

```
{Unit0}  => {IPAddress => 10.5.52.60, Name => 440_6PT_6AS_inf4, Port = 10_10},
{Unit1}  => ...
```

I have been able to create an array of all of the important lines by doing the following:

```
if (line =~ /WaTestProfile,Unit[\d+]/)
  # Manipulate the data first to remove pesky special characters
  result = line.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z,\.\,\{\}\_ ]/, '')
  if result !~ /DDOS|PhysIf/
    temp_line += [ "#{result}" ]
  end
end
```

Then I can use some regex to pull out the specific fields:

```
unit_array.sort.each_with_index do |line, idx|
  if result = line.match(/W[a|r]TestProfile,Unit(?:\d+),AdminIPAddress\s+\{(.*)\}/)
    temp = result.captures
    ip_array += [ temp ]
    printf "I captured #{temp}\n"
  end
  if result = line.match(/W[a|r]TestProfile,Unit(?:\d+),Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString\s+\{(.*)\}/)
    temp = result.captures
    port_array += [ temp]
    printf "I have captured #{temp}\n"
  end
  if result = line.match(/W[a|r]TestProfile,Unit(?:\d+),Interface,0,Name\s+\{(.*)\}/)
    temp = result.captures
    name_array += [ temp ]
    printf "Finally, I captured #{temp}\n"
  end
end
```

This puts everything into three separate arrays: top down from Unit 0 to 5, but I can't take it to the next step and stick those in a multi-dimensional array and I think the above code could also be improved.

```
WaTestProfile,Unit0,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {10_10}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf5}\
WaTestProfile,Unit0,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {10}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {8_8}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf4}\
WaTestProfile,Unit1,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {8}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {2_2}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf1}\
WaTestProfile,Unit2,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {2}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {4_4}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf2}\
WaTestProfile,Unit3,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {4}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {6_6}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf3}\
WaTestProfile,Unit4,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {6}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,AdminIPAddress                                      {10.5.52.60}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks                             {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSConfig                              {}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled                             {off}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString                  {0_0}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,Name                                    {440_6PT_6AS_inf0}\
WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,PhysIf                                  {0}\
```

Comment: Could you maybe clarify and clean up the post a little bit? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are asking, and also what the configuration data even is.

Comment: Absolutely.  Sorry about that.

Comment: could you clear up the configuration data? Or is that the exact format you are getting it in, including the slashes? What is the separation between the data? Is one "property" something like `WaTestProfile,Unit5,AdminIPAddress {10.5.52.60}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSAttacks {}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSConfig {}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,DDOSEnabled {off}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,InterfaceDisplayString {0_0}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,Name {440_6PT_6AS_inf0}\ WaTestProfile,Unit5,Interface,0,PhysIf {0}\`?

Comment: I figured out the correct format to fix the configuration data.  Each line in the configuration starts with WaTestProfile and ends with the \.  The formatting of the page doesn't include the extra spacing that's also included, but that's simple enough to handle with regex.  The values from each line is always included in curly braces like {10.5.52.60} for an IP Address.  The commas are also included in the configuration file.

One line would be like this:
WaTestProfile,Unit0,AdminIPAddress {10.5.52.60}\

Comment: For reference, next time to format stuff as code highlight it all and hit `ctrl+k`. You were using block comments, which isn't what you want. You could also have just added a double space to the end of each line, but that's way more difficult.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this is probably what you are looking for though it was kind of hard to understand the question. Here's my solution and I'll go over each part.

```
hsh = Hash.new()

File.open('config.txt', 'r').each_line do |line|
  match =
  /WaTestProfile,
    (?<unit>Unit\d+)  # match the unit and unit number
    ,.*               # match the comma and all the way up to the property
    (?<property>AdminIPAddress|InterfaceDisplayString|Name) # match the property
    \s+               # match all spaces up to the property value
    {(?<property_value>.*)} # match the property value
  /x =~ line

  if match
    hsh[unit.to_sym] ||= {}
    hsh[unit.to_sym][property.to_sym] = property_value
  end
end

hsh.each do |key, value|
  puts key.to_s + value.to_s
end
```

---

So this is just creating a hash, we also could have done `hsh = {}`

```
hsh = Hash.new()
```

---

We then open the file for reading and read each line in. On each line we attempt to find a match. I've used a more advanced form of regex here using named captures and ignoring whitespace because it's a little more complicated, so it makes it easier to read

```
  match =
  /WaTestProfile,
    (?<unit>Unit\d+)  # match the unit and unit number
    ,.*               # match the comma and all the way up to the property
    (?<property>AdminIPAddress|InterfaceDisplayString|Name|PhysIf) # match the property
    \s+               # match all spaces up to the property value
    {(?<property_value>.*)} # match the property value
  /x =~ line
```

Now I can reference the variable `unit` and get the entire unit and unit number.
We also use the `match =` at the start so that we can remove the DDOS lines from the equation.

---

Finally we check if there was a match. If there was we either create a new key corresponding to a hash in the top level hash or we grab an existing one. Then we set the property to the correct property value. I assumed since you didn't put quotes around the keys that you wanted them to be symbols, which is probably a better idea anyway.

```
  if match
    hsh[unit.to_sym] ||= {}
    hsh[unit.to_sym][property.to_sym] = property_value
  end
```

---

The final output looks like this:

```
Unit0{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"10_10", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf5"}
Unit1{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"8_8", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf4"}
Unit2{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"2_2", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf1"}
Unit3{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"4_4", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf2"}
Unit4{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"6_6", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf3"}
Unit5{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"0_0", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf0"}
```

All contained in the hash `hsh`

Psst:
If you want a shorter version, here it is:

```
hsh = {}

File.open('config.txt', 'r').each_line do |line|
  if /WaTestProfile,(?<unit>Unit\d+),.*(?<property>AdminIPAddress|InterfaceDisplayString|Name)\s+{(?<property_value>.*)}/x =~ line
    hsh[unit.to_sym] ||= {}
    hsh[unit.to_sym][property.to_sym] = property_value
  end
end

p hsh
```

Output:

```
{:Unit0=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"10_10", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf5"}, :Unit1=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"8_8", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf4"}, :Unit2=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"2_2", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf1"}, :Unit3=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"4_4", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf2"}, :Unit4=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"6_6", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf3"}, :Unit5=>{:AdminIPAddress=>"10.5.52.60", :InterfaceDisplayString=>"0_0", :Name=>"440_6PT_6AS_inf0"}}
```

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct then? It would be much appreciated :D